# Keep listbox selection the same after closing and reopening

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox in Access with the ability to select from three items. When I close the database the listbox does not save the item which I selected, but reverts back to the first item in the list of three. How can I save the selection I made when I close and reopen the database. I know there is a way to have a default selection, but I'd like to keep my latest selection, instead of it reverting to the default.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered saving the last selection with a user Id to a table?

Comment: I haven't thought/tried a user ID table. My assumption was there must be a setting in the Properties table, however I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I agree with Fionnuala, that is probably your best option to do exactly what you want to do.  Though in case there is possibly another option can you expand on why you are trying to do what you are doing and perhaps we could provide an alternative solution.

Comment: Best solution = save to table, reset on load. Another (but ugly) is to have code find the item selected, save the selection ID in someplace like the 'Tag' field, then have code in the open event to set selection if needed. You would need to SAVE the changes on close. Possible? Yes. Good idea? No.

Comment: Thanks. I tied the listbox to a new table with my selections. I am now able to refresh the database and the listbox selection does not change (it did when I had a default value). My question would be how do I save the selected values in the listbox so that when I reopen the database my values are still there?

Comment: The suggestion was to create a table (i.e. tblSettings) with a field (i.e. MyListboxID) and whenever you select an entry from your listbox, save the ID in the table. Then on opening the form, add code that checks the table, then selects the proper line from the listbox. Or if you allow 'multiselect' - and you are the only user of the database, add a flag to your new table (i.e. WasSelected) and update the flags as needed.