# Save Selections on Access Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am very new to Microsoft Access and would like to save a `ListBox` selection to a `Form`. Below is more detail:

I have placed a `ListBox` on my `Form` with three selection options Local, Regional, National. The three selections are tied to a `Table`. When I click through the three options I am able to choose between the three. When I `Refresh All` my selection remains the same. However, when I save and close out of the database and reopen, my `ListBox` reverts back to Local, presumably because it is the first option in my `Table`. I've tried to solve this problem by creating a `Default Value`. The `Default Value` would be the most commonly used category of Local, Regional, or National. The problem with this is when I `Refresh All` with a `Default Value` my `ListBox` reverts back to the default automatically *before* any other actions can take place. What I'd like for it to do, in the most simple way possible (again because I am so new to Access) is for the `Form` to save my selection. (i.e. when I close and reopen my database the `Listbox` displays what I last selected and not Local or the first value in my table).

Once I've achieved this I would also like to create a formula in a separate text box that says `IIF(ListBox = "Local" then do this` When I tried this formula, I also had trouble (my formula did not recognize the ListBox selection as Local, Regional, etc) This may be a separate question, or may actually be relevant depending on the ultimate solution to the original problem.

I've tried a number of things, including using a `Default Value`, replacing the `ListBox` with a `Textbox` and `OptionGroup`, both of which function in the same way as a `ListBox`. I've also tried to add the macro `SaveRecord` to the Event property section `After Update`.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact RowSource for the listbox?

Comment: The Row Source is a Table called Radius. The Row Source Type is Table/Query.

Comment: So the table Radius has three rows with the values "Local", "Regional", and "National"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The ListBox allow me to select from the Table either Local, Regional, or National.

Comment: Chris, tsk, tsk, you made a duplicate post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676459/keep-listbox-selection-the-same-after-closing-and-reopening   really not a good idea... If you don't understand responses you get, please say so. If you want to open a duplicate question, please mention that in your old post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and more common solution is to have an external ini file where you can save your option. During the Load Event you can load the ini file.

This is taken from a database that I developed. You can adapt them to your needs

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Load configuration file if existing
' Return False if not loaded
' Each valid line is in the form <Keyword>=<Value>
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function LoadConfig(strCfgFilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim vnt As Variant
    Dim strReadLine As String
    Dim intNumParams As Integer

    LoadConfig = False                      ' Set default return value to False (w/ errors)

    '-------------------------------------------------
    ' Exit if config file not found
    '-------------------------------------------------
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    If Not fso.FileExists(strCfgFilePath) Then
        Set fso = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(strCfgFilePath)           ' Open config file

    intNumParams =1                     ' Fixed number of parameters that must be read

    '-------------------------------------------------
    ' LOOP - Read all lines of the config file
    '
    Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream

        strReadLine = ts.ReadLine               ' Read a line
        vnt = Split(strReadLine, "=")               ' Extract the words from the line read

        '-------------------------------------------------
        ' IF - 2 words must be found
        '
        If Not IsEmpty(vnt) Then
            If UBound(vnt) = 1 Then

                Select Case CStr(vnt(0))

                    Case "RegionalSetting"          ' Keyword of the parameter to be read
                        g_strRegionalSettings = vnt(1)      ' Assign parameters to global variables
                        intNumParams = intNumParams - 1

            'Add parameters here ....

                End Select

            End If
        End If
        '
        ' END IF - 2 words must be found
        '-------------------------------------------------

    Loop
    '
    ' LOOP END - Read all lines of the config file
    '-------------------------------------------------

    If intNumParams = 0 Then
        LoadConfig = True                   ' Set result = TRUE if all params has been read
    End If

    ts.Close                            ' Close config file
    Set ts = Nothing                        ' Release memory
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

---

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Write configuration file
' Return False in case of errors
' Lines are in the form <Keyword>=<Value>
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function WriteConfig(strCfgFilePath As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_WriteConfig

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(strCfgFilePath, True)           ' Create text file (Overwrite if existing)
    ts.WriteLine "RegionalSetting" + "=" + g_strRegionalSettings    ' Write lines
    WriteConfig = True                          ' Set result = TRUE

Exit_WriteConfig:

    ts.Close                                ' Close file and release memory
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_WriteConfig:

    WriteConfig = False                          ' Set result to FALSE in case of any errors

End Function
```

---

You can set the global variable g_strRegionalSettings to the value of the ListBox during the Select event (when you click the setting you want).

You can call the WriteConfig when you close your database.
With the same routing you can manage other settings you want to save.

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Bye:-)